# Insert hyperlinks in Gridview table c# from uploaded excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am building a news page in a web tool using c# and visual studio. The idea is that you upload news in a specific excel format (newsID, Date, Header and text columns) and can view it in the web tool.

I managed to be able to upload the news, store it in a database table and print the news in a Gridview table with three columns: date, header and text. See the below screenshot:

[image: screenshot of newspage]

**My problem:** is that currently I can only print plain text in the Gridview table; but I want to be able to insert hyperlinks in the text column. Is it possible to do this without hard-coding the full HTML for the link into the news message before uploading it?.

This is my default.aspx part of the table:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll">
    <asp:GridView CssClass="gridview" ID="News" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Header" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"/>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="centered" style="width: 800px; overflow: auto; word-break: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; height: 70px;">
                        <%# Eval("Text")%>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And this the c# code behind in default.aspx.cs:

```cs
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable News page only for logged in users
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            GetData();
        }
    }

    protected void GetData()
    {
        News.Columns[0].Visible = true;
        string Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Date], [Header], [Text] FROM [ART].[News Indicator] ORDER BY [NewsID] DESC"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        News.DataSource = ds;
                        News.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
}}}
```

Comment: What type of project is this? Asp.Net Web Forms? How do you bind the Gridview, show the code.

Comment: It is an Asp.Net Web form

Comment: The please add the Tag so one cab see it from the questions page!

Comment: You are close to getting that working...just replace the <div> with my <asp:HyperLink...>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the AutoGenerateColumns property to False, you have a lot of control over the columns and you can control the content.

Then use `ItemTemplate` with HyperLink:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink  NavigateUrl='www.microsoft.com' Text='Whatever you want to be visible'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now the user sees on the screen the value of the Text property, but on click it takes him to page which is the value of NavigateUrl.

Comment: The point is that I have to upload the hyperlink in an excel file. So the hyperlink is stored between normal text in a database table column. Do you have any idea how I can print the text including clickable URL in the gridview table?

Comment: What is the URL that you have in the DB? It should still be http://www.microsoft.com, right? The NavigateUrl is the HyperLink and the Text property is what the user sees. The combination of both is what you are looking for.

Comment: It should work for any URL in the database. For example, I want to display this message in gridview table column: ''Hello, how are you ", where you is a hyperlink with for example www.google.nl as URL

Comment: That's my ultimate goal. But I am already happy if i can display this: 'Hello, how are you (www.google.com)', where www.google.com is a hyperlink

Comment: So now I realize you just want part of the full text to be the URL.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I mean.

Comment: I, also, cannot hard-code the url and text, instead I have to read that from my database table containing the news items

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What is the problem if the user clicks on the entire text of the column and that takes them to the URL, e.g. "Hello, how are you", by clicking this full text, you go to google.com?. If that is fine, follow my post and it is done. I guess, you can have several hyperlinks in one line of text...? I don't think it is possible to have hyperlink for just part of the text in the same column. Best shot would be to find a way to nest text column with a hyperlink column inside it, where the hyperlink is only that text that you want to be clickable.

Comment: I have one final question. I want to give every cell a different hyperlink, which are stored in a column of the database. My code for this is now: <asp:HyperLink runat ="server" style="color:black;" NavigateUrl=<%# Eval("URL")%>/> Text=<%# Eval("Text")%>/>

Comment: However, this does not work. Any idea how to do this. The NavigateUrl=<%# Eval("URL")%>/>  should change, but I don't know how